# Decimal numbers in Python are displayed as floats

Tags: python

I have defined my variables as decimal but they are still output as float when I print them.

My actual problem has complex calculations and I want to print the values to verify my results but I’m getting floats not decimals.
Does this simply not matter as the calculations will come out correctly?

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext
getcontext().prec = 6

a=Decimal(0.4)
print(a)
b=Decimal(0.3)
print(b)
x=(a/b)
print("x="+str(x))
```

Output

```
0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
x=1.33333


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

**Update**

This makes for some pretty silly looking code.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext
from random import random
getcontext().prec = 6

a=Decimal(str(random()))
print(a)
b=Decimal(str(random()))
print(b)
x=(a/b)
print("x="+str(x))
```

**Result** 
I still didn’t get the precision as I was expecting but I can work with that :)

```
0.27010708573406494
0.9726705675299723
x=0.277696
```

** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal

Comment: Correct way to use the `Decimal()` in this case is to pass the values with quotes. Have you tried `Decimal('0.4')` instead of `Decimal(0.4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't exactly figure out what's causing this issue, but wrapping the decimals around quotes solved it for me:

```
a=Decimal("0.4")
print(a)
b=Decimal("0.3")
print(b)
x=(a/b)
print("x="+str(x))
```

Edit: It's probably because the decimals are being initialized with the float values instead

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why it goes wrong and how to address it.

Comment: You are shitting me :) I just found this l Floating point numbers must be converted to a string before being used to create a Decimal”